# Sorting not working in Mongoose and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sorting, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
I am trying to sort my data by price, descending. In the following controller, I am able to filter for operations like greater than less than, less than or equal to... However, I create an if statement to check if a query has sort (localhost:3000/api/v1/tours?sort=price) and it does, so then in the block code, I am trying to sort. What ends up happening with the code below is the error

{
        "status": "failure",
        "results": "Parameter \"filter\" to find() must be an object, got price"
    }
```

I am taking a course where students are using Mongoose 5 and I am using 6. Whenever I use other code like--for the if statement--

```
if (queryString.sort) {
      queryString = queryString.sort(req.query.sort);
    }
```

then I get errors like

```
{
    "status": "failure",
    "results": "queryString.sort is not a function"
}
```

in my postman application. It almost seems as if the code in my if statement is ignored or tramples into an error.

```
exports.getAllTours = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        let queryString = JSON.stringify(req.query);
        queryString = queryString.replace(
          /\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g,
          (match) => `$${match}`
        );
        let = queryString = JSON.parse(queryString);
    
        if (queryString.sort) {
          queryString = queryString.sort;
        }
        const tours = await Tour.find(queryString);
    
        res
          .status(200)
          .json({ status: 'ok', results: tours.length, data: { tours } });
        //TODO: Will fine tune error despite somewhat working
      } catch (err) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(err);
        res.status(404).json({ status: 'failure', results: err.message });
      }
    };
```

Here are some questions I am having:

1. How do I use Mongoose's sort function appropriately in this scenario?

Comment: @ryan My data returns however the prices are not sorted. Here's the actual query posted in Postman localhost:3000/api/v1/tours?sort=price

Answer (score 0):

put the query code inside the if statements to find() all data, then added `.sort()` method.

If you want to sort it by price and only show data that qualified, you can try this:

```
let queryString = req.query;
let tours;

if (queryString.sort) {
  tours = await Tour.find({
    [queryString.sort]: {
      $gt: value,
      $lt: value
    }
  })
  .sort({
    [queryString.sort]: -1
  })
}

res
  .status(200)
  .json({ status: 'ok', results: tours.length, data: { tours } });
```

More info you can visit [MongoDB `.sort()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter and sort at same time then you can try

````
let queryString = req.query;
let API;

if(queryString.filter){
  API = Tour.find(queryString.filter);
}

if(queryString.sort){
  API = API.sort({[queryString.sort]: -1});
}

let tours = await API.exec();

res
  .status(200)
  .json({ status: 'ok', results: tours.length, data: { tours } });```
````

Comment: Thanks. Currently I am following along in a Udemy course. I think we might get to this point where we are filtering and sorting. Question, I have noticed that method? used exec(). I am not acquainted with that. What does that do? I'll look into it too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I had to use JSON.parse inside the find method.

```
exports.getAllTours = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        let queryString = JSON.stringify(req.query);
        queryString = queryString.replace(
          /\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g,
          (match) => `$${match}`
        );
    
        let query = Tour.find(JSON.parse(queryString));
    
        if (req.query.sort) {
          query = query.sort(req.query.sort);
        }
    
        const tours = await query;
        res
          .status(200)
          .json({ status: 'ok', results: tours.length, data: { tours } });
        //TODO: Will fine tune error despite somewhat working
      } catch (err) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(err);
        res.status(404).json({ status: 'failure', results: err.message });
      }
    };
```